# How to get JSON array on client_JS from server_JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From nodeJS (with Express) I try to send JSON_array in response to client JS:

```
asksJsonArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", 'utf-8'));

app.get('/getArr', function (req, res) {
    readJsonContent();
    res.json(JSON.stringify(TasksJsonArray)); //sending JSON array to client_JS in response
});
```

On client-side I want to get it, but nothing receive:

```
$.get('/getArr').success(function(res) {
  var currencyData = JSON.parse(res);
  if (!currencyData.rates) {
    // possibly handle error condition with unrecognized JSON response
    alert("currency data not found!");
  } else {
    taskArr = currencyData;
  }
})
```

So I always receive msg 'currency data not found!' ...

Comment: In the clientside code try just console logging `res` and see what you get, most likely it's already an object and shouldn't be parsed again. Also, `res.json` parses things into valid JSON you don't have to stringify it.

Comment: nothing shown in JS console(

Comment: So `$.get` is getting nothing, but it's still entering the success callback?

Comment: I receive response in success(function(res){ } So thats mean I receive response from nodeJS_side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.json` already converts the data to JSON, so you don't have to do it manually:

```
res.json(TasksJsonArray);
```

I believe this will also set the appropriate headers, so on the client, you don't have to explicitly parse the JSON, jQuery will do it for you:

```
$.get('/getArr').done(function(currencyData){
  if (!currencyData.rates) {
    // possibly handle error condition with unrecognized JSON response
    alert("currency data not found!");
  } else {
    taskArr = currencyData;
  }
});
```

Please note that assigning the response to a free variable is not really useful since you won't know when it's "safe" to access the variable. You might want to have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) .

This may still not work since `currencyData` might be a value that does not have a `rates` property. To learn how to correctly access the data, have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Comment: Yes, Express library also set headers. But if I use res(TasksJsonArray), so I receive in JS console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' that show on first line in my index.html (

Comment: Why are you using `res(TasksJsonArray)`? That should not even work.

Comment: cause I have working example with such sending response: res.json({value: value}); Its work perfect

Comment: I'm confused. In your first comment you say *"If I use `res(...)` ..."* and now your saying you use `res.json(...)`. Can you please decide on what you are using?

Comment: Also did you remove the `JSON.parse` call from the client as shown in my answer? If you don't do that it won't work. I have the feeling you didn't really read my answer...

Comment: sorry 4 mistake. I use 'res.json()' everywhere, because Express library send JSON response this way ..

Comment: Yes, I did as you wrote but receive 'currency data not found!' message

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(currencyData)`? You are most likely not accessing the data correctly. (you named your variable `TasksJsonArray`, so if this is really an array, then `currencyData.rates` cannot work, since arrays don't have such a property). Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196 to learn how.

Comment: In console Array[43] with my 43 objects

Comment: As I said, arrays don't have a `rates` property (proof: `console.log([].rates)` logs `undefined`). One or more objects inside the array may have a `rates` property. You to decide now which of the 43 objects you want to access (or if you want to access all of them). Have a look at the link I posted, it should help you further. But least you have the data now.

Comment: So maybe u know how to get values fron this JSON array? I see it in consile as Array[42] of objects. But when I try to get Arr[0].task - nothing shown(

Comment: @Spacemaster: Since I don't know the data structure I can't help you. The linked question should contain all the information you need to figure it out on your own.

Comment: > console.log(data.items[1])
  Object
     id: 2
     name: "bar"
     __proto__: Object
This tells us that data.items[1] is an object, and after expanding it we see that it has three properties, id, name and __proto__. The latter is an internal property used for the prototype chain of the object. The prototype chain and inheritance is out of scope for this answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Alter `res.json(JSON.stringify(TasksJsonArray));` to `res.send(JSON.stringify(TasksJsonArray));`.

Comment: server_sideJS use Express library, So res.json(JSON.stringify(TasksJsonArray)) sending response to client without res.send ..

Comment: @Spacemaster: The point is that you either have to use `res.send` or drop `JSON.stringify`.